# apt update isn't working on Debian 9

Tags: debian, apt

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free 
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Whenever I try to execute the following command,

```
apt update OR apt-get update
```

It is stuck at:

```
0% [Connecting to http.debian.net (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14)]
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: it didn't worked, i am also not able to install any apt packags.

Comment: As the output you show clearly shows problems with IPv6 connectivity, you should have a new situation after disabling IPv6, please tell us!

Answer (score 2):

`http://http.debian.net/debian` does not seem to contain a Debian package repository, so your `sources.list` settings need updating.

Also, your `sources.list` mentions `wheezy`. That's the release name for Debian 7, not Debian 9. What is the output of `cat /etc/debian_version` for you?

If it reports a number starting with 7, you're running Debian 7 ("Wheezy"), not Debian 9. In that case, you should think very carefully about upgrading: the Long Term Support for Debian 7 ends at 2018-05-31, that is in two months.

You'll find the correct settings for your `sources.list` file for Debian 7 LTS from here:

https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

If `cat /etc/debian_version` reports a number starting with 9, you should use the `sources.list` settings shown in Kiwy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Debian 9, your file `/etc/apt/sources.list` should look like this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

[Wheezy LTS will be supported until 31th of May 2018](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using).

Answer (score 1):

Please Disable ipv6 in sysctl 
add strin in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

`sysctl -p` or reboot